# How to change the order of form and tree views in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I created a module with normal settings which shows a form view and a tree view.
The default behavior is to show the form view at first.
I need to change this and show the tree view as the default view.

I tried to use the sequence attribute and changed the values with different values but it didn't solve the problem

```xml
<field name="sequence" >1</field>
```

Also, I tried to change the order in the `view_mode` attribute:

```xml
<field name="view_mode" >tree,form</field>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First We Need to change the Order of the  **ir.actions.act_window** and 
see Below

**Sample Demo for the customer(partner)**

```xml
<record id="base.action_partner_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Customers</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form,kanban</field>
    <field name="domain">[('customer','=',1)]</field>
    <field name="context">{'default_customer':1, 'search_default_customer':1}</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="base.view_res_partner_filter"/>
    <field name="filter" eval="True"/>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to add a contact in your address book.
        </p><p>
            OpenERP helps you easily track all activities related to
            a customer: discussions, history of business opportunities,
            documents, etc.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

Also change the sequence of view something like this

```xml
<record id="base.action_partner_tree_view1" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="sequence" eval="0"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="base.action_partner_form"/>
</record>
<record id="base.action_partner_form_view2" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="base.action_partner_form"/>
</record>
<record id="base.action_partner_form_view1" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="2" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="base.res_partner_kanban_view"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="base.action_partner_form"/>
</record>
```

Above code working well in my side.

I hope this should helpful for you .. :)

Comment: changing the default view from tree to form can be done by changing the order of `view_mode` from `tree, form` to `form, tree`

Comment: not possible every time becuase we are creating the so many form view ,tree view ,seach view for the same object